# How to use PowerShell to access methods and properties of a Third-Party OLE DLL?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, com, ole

I am trying to write a PowerShell script which could access methods and properties of a third-party OLE DLL.

The software vendor provided a working example in vbscript to achieve the same result. Below is an excerpt of the codes:

```
Set objOLE = CreateObject("NETIQOLE.APPMANAGER")
objOLE.Logon strInstance, strRepository, strUserID, strPwd
...
```

However, when I tried to code in PowerShell as below:

```
$objOLE = New-Object -ComObject "NETIQOLE.APPMANAGER"
$objOLE | Get-Member
```

I got output below and didn't see any relevant method or property.

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject

Name                      MemberType Definition                                                     
----                      ---------- ----------                                                     
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                 
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()                                              
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()                             
GetType                   Method     type GetType()                                                 
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()                      
ToString                  Method     string ToString()
```

Is there anything I can do to access to this OLE Dll's methods and proerties? Any advice or sample codes are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try executing `$objOLE.Logon(strInstance, strRepository, strUserID, strPwd)`?

Comment: See if http://www.sorrell.mcleod.co.uk/Scotty/powershell/COMinterop.htm helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your kind responses. The link given by @Ekkehard.Horner worked. It really save my day.

The working codes are now:

```
$credential = "...", "...", "...", "..."
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Logon", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $netiqObj, $credential)
```